# HTTP breaks over WiFi

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, http

My WiFi continually breaks for HTTP connections every ~10 minutes. Reconnecting to my router's AP does not fix it, but disabling and enabling the adapter does work.

I thought it could be an IP conflict, but other protocols like GTalk and Torrents strangely continue to function. Browsers just show "Sending request..."

Since I recently replaced my mainboard, my first thought was power-saving, but disabling it for my WiFi adapter did not solve the problem.

This leads me to believe it's a software issue. The only software I recently installed is iTunes. I've checked my firewall and disabled Peerblock, but no luck.

What could be breaking my HTTP connections?

---

**Update:** Could be DNS related. When sites start to hang, I can still connect to my Netgear router @ 192.168.0.1 and successfully ping the Google.com IP via its interface. What could be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

Reinstalled 2009 D-Link WiFi drivers along with D-Link's horrible network monitoring app.

Answer (score 3):

I would try to download and a Linux LiveCD like ubuntu. If you experience the same problem then you know it's hardware related or firmware related or router related.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a software issue.

Answer (score 1):

That you said other protocols continue to function leads me to believe that you browser is at fault. Yes, disabling the network adapter will clear it, so it looks like it is related, but it probably is your specific browser having a connection issue.

Try using a different browser temporarily, and go to some other sites, which you might not go to normally (try msnbc.com and usatoday.com since they are mainstream...click around for 10-20 minutes). See if it still happens. If the answer is no, then you can see what you can do to repair your browser.

Another thing that comes to mind is that you should run a few scanners, and make sure you are not infected: Malwarebytes, Superantispyware, and Hitman Pro are my favorites.

Comment: Same symptoms on Firefox 4 and Chrome 14. Could be malware.

Comment: Latest Malwarebytes revealed nothing. I also run the latest AVG Free.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your browser on a laptop?

I had a very similar problem on a laptop running Vista. When it was running on the battery (not plugged in) it was simply going into power saving mode (after 10mins or so) and my HTTP connection over WiFi kept acting strange (resetting).  I turned the power saving off and suddenly it never happened again.

Comment: ... except FreshCode said that transfers using other protocols, like torrents, continue to work. If the network card turned off, they would stop.

Comment: Desktop. Already turned off power-saving for my D-Link WiFi adapter, did not solve the issue.